# What is resize ,transformation of image in Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I would like to know more details about what is transformation of image in Picasso what will happen if i use transformation for image in android  and what is  resize and transformation of image.

Comment: refer https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit

Comment: Refer these Links you will get some idea about picasso

http://square.github.io/picasso/ and  
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/picasso-android-tutorial-picasso-image-loader-library

Answer for your question

https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations

Comment: is it mean will use transformation for display image in rounded ,Gray-scale,sepia etc ? and resizing means image will resize with required width and height?

Comment: As simple as I understood above details about it ,Please may i know if Still any wrong or any info about it .

Answer (score 0):

Picasso.resize(50, 50)
resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel). does not respect aspect ratio

The transformations will give you enough tools to change the image according to your needs.